# docker-compose mysql Connection refused

Tags: docker, docker-compose

my development environment

- Spring Boot 2.x, Gradle, Mybatis

Simply build through Docker-compose and create a project for API testing.
Why do I keep getting connection refused?

If you type the command 'docker-compose up', it runs without any problem.

I checked the network and it is connected.

I usually use 'docker exec A ping B' to check.

I don't know why an error occurs when A is a DB container.
I'll attach the code just in case.

```
# application.properties
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://test-db:3306/exdocker?serverTimezone=Asia/Seoul
spring.datasource.username=dockerex
spring.datasource.password=12341234
```

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: "3"
services:
  test-db:
    container_name: test-db
    image: mysql:8.0
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "exdocker"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "root"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "12341234"
      MYSQL_USER: "dockerex"
    restart: always
    networks:
      - exdocker-network
    ports:
    - 3307:3306

  test-app:
    links:
      - test-db
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
    - 8081:8080
    restart: always
    networks:
      - exdocker-network
    depends_on:
      - test-db

networks:
  exdocker-network:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.202.0.1/16
```

Comment: In docker compose , to access the other container you just need to use the service name

Comment: have you checked if the mysql is up and running? it might take some time before mysql could handle connections. Also try using telnet (or nc) on the app container and test connectivity to the mysql pod (something like `nc test-db 3306` and make sure the server responds

Comment: I do not know what it is, but I solved it with the 'docker system prune' command.

I don't know if it's cache related. It's embarrassing.